# How can I solve "OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded"?

Tags: disk-usage, quota

I run a python3 script and the program will output several JSON files with about 114.17 MB each. But after generating about 60 files, I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dlp.py", line 206, in <module>
    json.dump(prediction, fp, indent=2)
OSError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded
```

I execute `quota` command but no output (same as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703323/why-would-the-quota-command-not-work-at-all)).

Here is my disk statistic:

```
$ df -i .
Filesystem                        Inodes    IUsed      IFree IUse% Mounted on
head03-10g:/share/home1/zhusf 6835937472 37193534 6798743938    1% /share/home1/zhusf

$ df -h .
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
head03-10g:/share/home1/zhusf  319T   79T  241T  25% /share/home1/zhusf
```

What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/916587/disk-quota-exceeded-on-nfs-how-can-i-see-the-quota . You'll either need to login to your nfs server and run `quota` there, or ask the administrators.